# C# client library for Oauth 2.0 and ADfs authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, adfs, client-library

I am working on web API and need to authenticate api using ADfs login.To make ADfs  authorization and authentication work i need to create custom code which follows Oauth 2.0 . Is their any client library or nuget package available for c# for ADfs authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend IdentityModel (https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/blob/dev/README.md).

Comment: Thanks for your information.will it work with any version of ADFS?

Comment: AFAIK ADFS has an OAuth 2 endpoint since version 3.0, so version 3 and newer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ADFS?

Ideally, you need ADFS 4.0.

The standard OWIN package for ADFS connect is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/).

Comment: ADFS 3.0 only has web API OAuth support. Refer http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/